# Flutter - Access Bloc from parent on children

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have a parent widget that has two Blocs:

```
...
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<RestaurantBloc>(
          create: (BuildContext context) => RestaurantBloc(restaurantRepository: _restaurantRepository),
        ),
        BlocProvider<CartBloc>(
          create: (BuildContext context) => CartBloc(),
        ),
      ],
      child: RestaurantScreenWidget(),
    );
  }
...
```

Section of the parent widget where child widgets get generated using the `CartBloc` and other Bloc:

```
...
BlocBuilder<RestaurantBloc, RestaurantState>(
  builder: (context, state) {
    if (state is RestaurantEmpty) {
      return Center(
        child: Text('Empty'),
      );
    }

    if (state is RestaurantLoaded) {
      final items = state.restaurantCategories;

      if (items.length >= 1) {
        return BlocBuilder<CartBloc, CartState>(
          builder: (context, cartState) {
            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <CategoryList>[
                for (var item in items)
                  CategoryList(categoryName: item.name, categoryItems: item.items)
              ],
            ); 
          },
        );
      }

      return Center(
        child: Text('Empty restaurant'),
      );
    }

    return Center(
      child: Text(
        'Error'
      ),
    );
  }
),
...
```

And then it generates various child widgets. Those widgets need access to `CartBloc` and its state:

```
...
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
  child: SizedBox(
    width: double.infinity,
    child: BlocBuilder<CartBloc, CartState>(
      builder: (context, cartState) {
        return RaisedButton(
          child: const Text('ADD TO BASKET'),
            color: Colors.blue,
             textColor: Colors.white,
             onPressed: () {
               BlocProvider.of<CartBloc>(context).add(
                 AddItemToCart(
                   itemCount: (state as ItemLoaded).amount,
                   itemPrice: args.itemPrice,
                   newItemId: args.itemId,
                   newItemRestrictions: (state as ItemLoaded).restrictions,
                   newItemName: args.itemName
                 )
               );
               Navigator.pop(context);
             },
           );
         } 
       ), 
     ),
   ),
   ...
```

But by doing it like this, It gives the error:

[image]

However, if I put a `MultiBlocProvider` with the `CartBloc` on the child widgets, the error goes away, but obviously the parent widget doesn't shares the state of the child widgets.

How can I handle the state that needs to be share between these two widgets? (The generate child widgets push to a screen that needs access to `CartBloc` and its state).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite a common mistake. When using the `BlocBuilder` widget, you must give it the bloc instance to 'build.' You can do this by setting the optional "bloc" constructor property in the `BlocBuilder`.

```
BlocBuilder<CameraBloc, CameraState>(
  bloc: CameraBloc(),
  builder: (context, state) {
    if (state is InitialCameraState) {
      return Container(
        child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
          child: CameraPreview(controller)));
    }

    return Container();
  },
);
```

Comment: I think this answer is not completely ok. In the question, it was stated that the parent widget is using a BlocProvider for creating the CartBloc, so, as I understand, the child widget should be able to get it. Doing what this answer instructs will create a new bloc instance, instead of using the same. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

In the parent widget (the one with MultiBlocProvider), wrap RestaurantScreenWidget with [Builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html).